# How can I simplify this statement?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

$\text {I've simplified one statement down to}\\ (p \wedge \neg q) ∨ (r \vee \neg q)
\\ \text{And I thought I could use the distributive laws to simplify this, but the operator inside the parentheses aren't the same. }
\\ \text {How would I simplify this? }$

$
\text{It apparently simplfies down to } 
\\(\neg q \vee r) 
\\ \text { according to Matlab/WolframAlpha but I'm not entirely sure how with the rules that I've learned.}
$

I don't necessarily need the solution, just the next step to get me closer to the solution.

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $$(p \wedge \neg q) ∨ (r \vee \neg q)$$The parenthesis surrounding $(r \vee \neg q)$ are not necessary here since we have an $\vee$ in the middle. So $$(p \wedge \neg q) ∨ r \vee \neg q$$

If $\neg q$ by itself is enough to make the statement true, then the $(p \wedge \neg q)$ is redundant.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to see that this is simplification is equivalent to ignoring the first term of the $\vee$. But why can that be done?

If you examine the first term, you'll see that it's only true if both $p$ and $\neg q$ are true. But if you check the second term, having $\neg q$ to be true would also make $(r\vee\neg q)$ true, allowing you to ignore the first term altogether.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know why I didn't see that.